# Finding the adjoint of a compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

Let $H = L^2([0,1])$ and $A:H \to H$ be defined as

$$
Af(t) = \int_0^t f(s) ds, \quad f \in H
$$
By the Ascoli-Arzela theorem, $A$ is compact. Now the adjoint of $A$ is given as

$$
A^\ast g(s) = \int_s^1 g(t) dt
$$

**Questions**

1. How does the Ascoli-Arzela theorem show that $A$ is compact?
2. More importantly, how was the adjoint $A^\ast$ determined? How do we get from the expression for $A$ to the expression for $A^\ast$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For determining the adjoint :

You have that

$$\langle Af, g \rangle = \int_0^1 g(t) \int_0^t f(s) ds dt $$

And this is equal (by Fubini) to

$$ = \int_0^1 f(t) \int_t^1 g(s) ds dt = \langle f, Bg \rangle$$

with $Bg(t) = \int_t^1 g(s) ds$

And as this is true for every $f$ and $g$, you have that $A^* = B$

Comment: I don't see how the limits of integration are switching from $0, t$ to $t, 1$ by Fubini? The versions of Fubini's theorem that I am looking at just say we can switch the the order of integration.

Comment: Well, draw a triangle like this  
$$\begin{array}{cc}&&\cdot\\&\nearrow &\uparrow\\\cdot&\rightarrow&\cdot\end{array}$$ Sorry this is primitive, but the shape is alike: you want the region inside the triangle, so, by switching variables, the limit changes.

Comment: The idea is that $$\int_0^1 g(t) \int_0^t f(s) ds dt =  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 g(t) f(s) \Bbb 1_{\{ s \leq t \}} ds dt $$ So by Fubini, $$ = \int_0^1 f(s)  \int_0^1 g(t) \Bbb 1_{\{ s \leq t \}} dt ds = \int_0^1 f(s)  \int_s^1 g(t) dt ds  $$

Answer (score 4):

For Questions 1, take $\{f_n\}$ be uniformly bounded in $L^2$, consider the class $\{Af_n\}$.

check 1.$\{Af_n\}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2$.

check 2.$\{DAf_n\}$ is well-define and uniformly bounded in $L^2$, where D is Differential operator.

pf of check 1:

This follows by Holder,

$|\int_0^t f(s) ds| \leq \sqrt{t }\|f_n\|_2\leq \|f_n\|_2$, so $\|Af_n\|_2\leq \|Af_n\|_\infty \leq \|f_n\|_2$

pf of check 2:

Since the form $\int_0^t f(s) ds$ is absolutely continuous, so $DAf_n=f_n$ is well-define and they are uniformly bounded in $L^2$ follows by assumption.

So by the Ascoli-Arzela theorem, there's a subsequence of $\{Af_n\}$ converge to a continuous function $f$ pointwise. On the other hand, since domain is finite and $\{Af_n\}$ are uniformly bounded in $L^2$, you can check by DCT that they converge in $L^2$. That means $A$ is compact.

Answer (score 3):

For $f\in L^2$ and $0 \le r \le s \le 1$,
\begin{align}
         |(Af)(r)-(Af)(s)| & \le \int_{r}^{s}|f(x)|dx \\
               & \le \left(\int_{r}^{s}|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{r}^{s}dx\right)^{1/2} \\
            & = \|f\|\sqrt{s-r}.
\end{align}
Therefore the imagine of a bounded subset of $L^2$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, which proves that $A$ is compact.

The adjoint is determined using integration by parts:
\begin{align}
      (Af,g) & = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\overline{g(x)}dx \\
     & = -\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\right)\left(\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{1}\overline{g(t)}dt\right)dx \\
     & = -\left.\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\int_{x}^{1}\overline{g(t)}dt\right|_{x=0}^{1}
   + \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\left(\int_{x}^{1}\overline{g(t)}dt\right)dx \\
     & =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\left(\overline{\int_{x}^{1}g(t)dt}\right)dx = (f,A^*g)
\end{align}